# Convert pandas DataFrame into string to be written to a cfg file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

***Target***

I have a Pandas data frame, as shown below, and would like to join the columns, `command` and `value` while also converting it back into it's raw string format to be written to a .cfg file.

---

***Data Frame*** - `df`:

*Before* joined:

```
   command                                              value
0     bind                                       "0" "slot10"
1     bind                                        "1" "slot1"
2     bind                                        "2" "slot2"
3     bind                                        "3" "slot3"
4     bind                                        "4" "slot4"
5     bind                                        "5" "slot5"
6     bind                                        "6" "slot6"
7     bind                                        "7" "slot7"
8     bind                                        "8" "slot8"
9     bind                                        "9" "slot9"
10    bind                                    "a" "+moveleft"
11    bind                                      "b" "buymenu"
12    bind                                   "d" "+moveright"
```

*After* joined:

```
0                          bind "0" "slot10"
1                           bind "1" "slot1"
2                           bind "2" "slot2"
3                           bind "3" "slot3"
4                           bind "4" "slot4"
5                           bind "5" "slot5"
6                           bind "6" "slot6"
7                           bind "7" "slot7"
8                           bind "8" "slot8"
9                           bind "9" "slot9"
10                      bind "a" "+moveleft"
11                        bind "b" "buymenu"
12                     bind "d" "+moveright"
13                           bind "e" "+use"
14                  bind "f" "+lookatweapon"
...
etc.
dtype: object
```

---

***My attempt***:

I have managed to combine two columns to get the output above using the following code:

```
df = df['command'].astype(str)+' '+df['value'].astype(str)
```

However, this still hasn't helped convert the dataframe into a raw string so that it can be written to a *.cfg* file .

I have also attempted to use `df.to_string()` but this doesn't seem to make a difference

---

***Expected Output***

I would like to get raw string output like so assigned under a variable to be written to a .cfg file:

```
bind "0" "slot10"
bind "1" "slot1"
bind "2" "slot2"
bind "3" "slot3"
bind "4" "slot4"
bind "5" "slot5"
bind "6" "slot6"
bind "7" "slot7"
bind "8" "slot8"
bind "9" "slot9"
bind "a" "+moveleft"
bind "b" "buymenu"
bind "d" "+moveright"
bind "e" "+use"
bind "f" "+lookatweapon"
...
etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you call

```
df = df['command'].astype(str)+' '+df['value'].astype(str)
```

you're actually left with a `Series` object, so you can call `df.tolist()` and then join the elements of the list with a newline. Something like this

```
s = df['command'].astype(str)+' '+df['value'].astype(str)
cfg_output = '\n'.join(s.tolist()) # joins each command with a newline
```

You're getting a None value appended to the last line because of how you're reading in the original config file, this line

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0].str.split(' ',1).tolist(),columns = ['command','value'])
```

has trouble accounting for a config setting without a value. Consider the last three lines of your original conf file

```
sensitivity "0.9"
cl_teamid_overhead_always 1
host_writeconfig
```

the settings for `sensitivity` and `cl_teamid_overhead_always` have values following them, but `host_writeconfig` doesn't, so when pandas tries to split on whitespace (which doesn't exist in that line), the first value is `host_writeconfig` and the second is the None object.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's great. The bottom of the output seems to have 3 random `None` statements. Should/Does this make a difference?

Comment: hard for me to tell without seeing your input tbh

Comment: that's not your "input", that's the code you're executing. the input here would be the contents of `"E:\\Steam\\userdata\\.........................config.cfg"`

Comment: Oh, Okay, thanks. Here are the [contents](https://hastebin.com/umanenoriw.bash). Thank You. (The program simply allows the user to change a value inside a config)

Comment: I've figured out why two of the None statements appear. It seems that the config file had two blank lines at the end that caused the error. However, it still only appears after the last command: https://hastebin.com/ofurobujeb.bash

Comment: @LearningToPython what does the line that contains `host_writeconfig` look like in the original config file?

Comment: [Screenshot](https://gyazo.com/00ab7ab94b507454cc8763e6567e6894) | There is literally no space/whitespace or anything for that matter after it. :/ Here's another direct paste of the original config file: https://hastebin.com/fahowifisi.bash - I have no idea :)

Comment: @LearningToPython updated my answer, hope that hleps

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for your time and help.